# How to fix this uploading error in nextJs?

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js, aws-sdk

I'm trying to upload files to s3 through a nextjs application. But once I install @aws-sdk/client-s3 to my next application, I'm getting following error.

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:30)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are 
configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

NextJs version - 9.3.4

AWS SDK/ client-s3 version - 3.317.0

Can someone help me to fix thos issue please?